# File Sharing between two routers

Tags: router, static-routes

i need help on setting up file sharing across two routers. the two routers were **DLink DIR-600 Wireless 150 Router**. **Router 1 lan address 192.168.5.1** and **router 2 is 192.168.10.1**. how can i setup up to make filesharing possible within the network? The network layout is:

```
ISP => Modem => Router 1 (192.168.5.1) 
                => PC 1 (via utp cable) (192.168.5.3) 
                => PC 2 (via utp cable) (192.168.5.4) 
                => PC 3 (via wireless) (192.168.5.5) 
                => Router 2 (via utp cable) (192.168.10.1) 
                          => PC 1 (via utp cable) (192.168.10.3)
                          => PC 2 (via wireless) (192.168.10.4)
```

router 2 is not in bridge mode by the way. should i configure static routes from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure Router 2 is not performing any NAT between the two networks, otherwise this is not going to work at all. Also, make sure Router 2 is not doing any firewalling between the two networks.

Then, you will need computers on the 192.168.5 network to know how to reach the 192.168.10 one; this can be done by adding a static route either on the PCs themselves, or on Router 1, which I assume is their default gateway. The static route should say "in order to reach the 192.168.10 network, go through Router 2". To do this, you will also need to know Router 2's IP address on the 192.168.5 network, which you didn't specify in your question.

If f.e. Router 2 has the 192.168.10.1 address on one side and 192.168.5.254 on the other one (and assuming both networks use a /24 subnet mask), the command to add the relevant static route on a Windows PC in the 192.168.5 network would be

```
route add 192.168.10.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.5.254
```

Answer (score 1):

The devices behind router 2 are in a different subnet so you need some kind of routing. Probably the easiest thing is to configure the static routes on either all PCs in subnet 192.186.5.* or on router 1. Configuring it on router 1 is probably the easiest solution. But maybe your router is not able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You more than likely stacking NATs which causes challenges with accessing file sharing from the front NAT (19.168.5.0) to shares on the back NAT (192.168.10.0). The following question provides additional information on the configuration - https://serverfault.com/questions/182111/airport-for-wifi-dlink-for-hardwired/182113#182113.